# Telegram bots not responding

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have created some new telegram bots to test their functionality. I haven't used them before, but I cannot seem to get them to respond to any commands?

[image]

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

You have created a telegram bot on telegram. However..

Did you set any webhooks for the bot?

You should set a webhook/polling and write a backend to make it response to your queries.

For reference you can start from here
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

Answer (score 0):

set the webhook for your bot.

Ex:

```
http://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/setWebhook?url=<ENDPOINT>
```